# Get all entries in resx file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, web-applications, resources

I'm using a .resx resource file to store some "dictionary" data, wich i want to display in a grid in my web app. let's say i have the "tags.resx" file, and using custom tool resxcodegenerator - i can access Tags.my_tag in C#. But what i need is a way to get all entries in my file in a collection.
Any ideas how could i do this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var allEntries = new ResourceManager(typeof(Tags))
        .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false, true);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but i get this error : Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "tags.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "BI" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Comment: Maybe you should look into the ResourceManager class on MSDN or something, I think it's the way to go. Good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks! I've found the solution, and edited your answer. Thanks for the help